# From Dingo To tymon JWT

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt

My app is `Laravel 5.4`

I removed Dingo/Api from my application and I want to use only Tymon JWT.

however we are on production and we have thousands of users. we cannot make them logout and login again. but when I removed Dingo, it required the user to login again cz it gave `Invalid Token Error`.

Is there a work around for this problem?

The Error I'm getting is

> Token Signature could not be verified

**UPDATE**

I *fixed* the issue by changing the jwt secret as it was before in app/jwt.php

Comment: How do you currently authorise users, through a JWT from Dingo? I've never used it so I'm not sure how it works.

Comment: Why is it so bad if they had to log in again?

Comment: @simon because we have around 200,000 users.. it's a bad experience for them and half of them don't remember their password